# Apply a function to groups within a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to get the cumulative sum of a variable (v) for groups ("a" and "b") within a dataframe. How can I get the result at the bottom -- whose rows are even numbered properly -- into column cs of my dataframe?

```
> library(nlme)
> g <- factor(c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"))
> v <- c(1,4,1,4,1,4,2,8,2,8,2,8)
> cs <- rep(0,12)
> d <- data.frame(g,v,cs)

> d
   g v cs
1  a 1 0
2  b 4 0
3  a 1 0
4  b 4 0
5  a 1 0
6  b 4 0
7  a 2 0
8  b 8 0
9  a 2 0
10 b 8 0
11 a 2 0
12 b 8 0

> r=gapply(d,FUN="cumsum",form=~g, which="v")
>r

$a     
   v   
1  1   
3  2   
5  3  
7  5  
9  7  
11 9  

$b    
    v 
2   4 
4   8 
6  12 
8  20 
10 28 
12 36 

> str(r)
List of 2
 $ a:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ v: num [1:6] 1 2 3 5 7 9
 $ b:'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ v: num [1:6] 4 8 12 20 28 36
```

I guess I could figure out some laborious way to get the data from those dataframes into d$cs, but there's got to be some easy tweak I'm missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `ave`.  If you look at the source of `ave`, you'll see it essentially wraps Martin Morgan's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645158/271616).

```
R> g <- factor(c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"))
R> v <- c(1,4,1,4,1,4,2,8,2,8,2,8)
R> d <- data.frame(g,v)
R> d$cs <- ave(v, g, FUN=cumsum)
R> d
   g v cs
1  a 1  1
2  b 4  4
3  a 1  2
4  b 4  8
5  a 1  3
6  b 4 12
7  a 2  5
8  b 8 20
9  a 2  7
10 b 8 28
11 a 2  9
12 b 8 36
```

Comment: I always forget about `ave`; though is the same out come as the other 2?

Comment: @TylerRinker: it's essentially the same as Martin's solution (see my edit).

Comment: I was confused b/c I compared to joran's.  I forgot plyr rearranges things. +1

Comment: Nice one, adding `ave` to my mental library of useful functions.

Comment: Thanks! This is the simplest so I'm going with it.

Comment: Can i put my own function to calculate cummulative sum?.(replacing `cumsum` with my own function ).In that case what would be my input to the function?

Answer (score 13):

`split<-` is a pretty weird beast

```
split(d$cs, d$g) <- lapply(split(d$v, d$g), cumsum)
```

leading to

```
> d
   g v cs
1  a 1  1
2  b 4  4
3  a 1  2
4  b 4  8
5  a 1  3
6  b 4 12
7  a 2  5
8  b 8 20
9  a 2  7
10 b 8 28
11 a 2  9
12 b 8 36
```

Comment: That was `split<-.default`.  I didn't realize it existed (or that it was the basis for ave.)  `split<-.data.frame` is even weirder.

Answer (score 7):

My tool of choice for these things is the **plyr** package:

```
require(plyr)
> ddply(d,.(g),transform,cs = cumsum(v))
   g v cs
1  a 1  1
2  a 1  2
3  a 1  3
4  a 2  5
5  a 2  7
6  a 2  9
7  b 4  4
8  b 4  8
9  b 4 12
10 b 8 20
11 b 8 28
12 b 8 36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(nlme)
> g <- factor(c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"))
> v <- c(1,4,1,4,1,4,2,8,2,8,2,8)
> cs <- rep(0,12)
> d <- data.frame(g,v,cs)
> d <- d[order(d$g),]
> temp <- by(d$v,d$g,cumsum)
> d$cs <- do.call("c",temp)
> d
   g v cs
1  a 1  1
3  a 1  2
5  a 1  3
7  a 2  5
9  a 2  7
11 a 2  9
2  b 4  4
4  b 4  8
6  b 4 12
8  b 8 20
10 b 8 28
12 b 8 36
```

Another solution using the by function, but I had to order the data first